# GRANT DELETE ON database.table TO username@'%';

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1142

I have given a user full control over one table in a database.  Hoever it appears they cant delete records.

I've tried as a privilaged user:

```
GRANT DELETE ON databasename.tablename TO username@'%';
flush privileges;
```

But delete stil doesn't work

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): DELETE command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Nathan.

Comment: Try granting them "USAGE" as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your GRANT statement might need additional quotes for the username: `'username'@'%'`.

You can check the user's privileges in the `mysql` database. Check the tables `user`, `db`, `hosts`, `tables_priv`.

You might have entries with the same username and different hostnames, like 'username'@'localhost' and 'username'@'%'.

The MySQL-Documentation describes in which order MySQL evaluates these tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/request-access.html

If you have an entry in the table `tables_priv` allowing the user to `DELETE`, that should normally be sufficient.

AFAIK you do not need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after a `GRANT` - you only need to `FLUSH` if you modify the privilege tables manually with INSERT,DELETE etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers of which mysql tables to look at.  Delete now working.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

May be your mySQL workbench does not allow the delete function on Global Privilege on your current user

Go to Administration - User and Privilege > Select User Account > Go to Administrative Roles Tab > then on Global Privileges check the DELETE.